# making a LCD dice for catan

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

when I go to upload the code, I get

```
 Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows Store 1.8.10.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
C:\Users\taran\Documents\Arduino\dice in progress\dice in progress1\diceinprogress\diceinprogress.ino:1:25: fatal error: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.10.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/"DFRkeypad.h": Invalid argument
#include <"DFRkeypad.h">
                     ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

and the code is

```
#include <"DFRkeypad.h">
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
const char* DFRkeypad::sKEY[]=                          { "---",       "Right",   "Up", "Down", "Left", "Select", "???" };
const int DFRkeypad::iARV_VALUES[DFRkeypad::eNUM_KEYS]= { 1023,        0,         143,  328,    504,     740,      -1   };
int btnSELECT;


void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
  lcd.print("Roll the dice!");
}

void loop() {
while (btnSELECT == 0){

  delay (50);
  buttonState = analogRead(btnSELECT);
}


 case btnSELECT:
     {
     lcd.print("Rolling dice");
       diceOne = random(1, 7);
       diceTwo = random(1, 7);
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have quotation marks around the first library you include and not the second (I believe you shouldn't have quotation marks). That's why it gives "invalid argument "DFRkeypad". Also make sure the library is properly installed and use some proven (library examples or off-the-web) testcode before slapping some code together.

Comment: You edit the question to ask a completely different questions. Different questions should be posted as different questions, otherwise the answers do not reflect the answer to the question anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ you either use the `#include` pre-processor statement in the form of

```
#include "someFile.h"
```

or

```
#include <someFile.h>
```

The form

```
#include <"someFile.h">
```

is not legal. You must correct it to one of the two forms above.

The difference between those forms is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77092/5296568.